# IronPython throws Dynamic operations can only be performed in homogenous AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net, ironpython

I am testing calls to IronPython from my C# DLL however I get following exception `Dynamic operations can only be performed in homogenous AppDomain.` from `var pythonResult = engine.Execute(theScript, scope);`. This problem appeared after I added a loop summarizing elements in my `testFunc`. This method works fine when I remove a loop summarizing elements.

I searched for this AppDomain stuff but I have found only things related to ASP.NET development and it is not related to my case at all.

```
            var theScript =
@"import sys
def testFunc():
    print list

    sum = 0;
    for i in list:
        sum += i

    return 3

testFunc()";

            var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
            var scope = engine.CreateScope();

            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            list.Add(2);
            list.Add(3);
            list.Add(7);
            scope.SetVariable("list", list);

            var pythonResult = engine.Execute(theScript, scope);
```

**This issue blocks me from further development. Any ideas?**